# FontAwesome and IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, font-awesome

The following code shows fine in FireFox but IE 9 does not want to display the font. Is there something I can try?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> fa-camera-retro
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use  Internet-Explorer 11, the font displays fine, hence you can update your IE browser.
Alternatively, if you needs the images from the font, then you can use they as "background-image".
E.g. somthing as follows:

```
<a style="background-image:url(Your-Image-From-Font.jpg)"></a>
```

or

```
<span style="background-image:url(Your-Image-From-Font.jpg)"></span>
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

From the FontAwesome documentation on GitHub, IE versions greater than 7 should be supported (more or less with some caveats). IE9 should be OK, but there are some issues with IE compatibility mode. The documentation instructs to disable IE compatibility mode by adding the following to your head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to check IE9? Is it a native machine, VM (like parallels), or something like BrowserStack? I've noticed BrowserStack has issues rendering webfonts at times, you may be getting a false error.

Try loading FontAwesome locally and see if the problem still persists.